# Deployed R app with Shiny crash with 'could not find function "httpdPort"'

Tags: r, shiny, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have an application built with `Shiny` (a tutorial, where `ui.R` and `server.R` are taken from here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/).
I have these two files in `shiny-frontend` folder, and if I `runApp("shiny-frontend")` locally in RStudio - everything works great and I see the tutorial in my browser.

Now I want the same app to be put into Bluemix via cloudfoundry. I'm using this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-rtwitter-app/ as a tutorial, but struggling with an error.

I have a `start.r` file which I run as `R -f ./start.r --gui-none --no-save`. I'm using https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r buildpack.

My `start.r` looks like this (taken from the bluemix tutorial with a very minor modifications):

```
library(shiny)

if (Sys.getenv('VCAP_APP_PORT') == "") {
  print("Running Shiny")
  runApp("shiny-frontend")
} else {
  # In case we're on Cloudfoundry, run this:
  print('running on CF')

  # Starting Rook server during CF startup phase - after 60 seconds start the actual Shiny server
  library(Rook)
  myPort <- as.numeric(Sys.getenv('VCAP_APP_PORT'))
  myInterface <- Sys.getenv('VCAP_APP_HOST')
  status <- -1

  # R 2.15.1 uses .Internal, but the next release of R will use a .Call.
  # Either way it starts the web server.
  if (as.integer(R.version[["svn rev"]]) > 59600) {
    status <- .Call(tools:::startHTTPD, myInterface, myPort)
  } else {
    status <- .Internal(startHTTPD(myInterface, myPort))
  }

  if (status == 0) {
    unlockBinding("httpdPort", environment(tools:::startDynamicHelp))
    assign("httpdPort", myPort, environment(tools:::startDynamicHelp))

    s <- Rhttpd$new()
    s$listenAddr <- myInterface
    s$listenPort <- myPort

    s$print()
    Sys.sleep(60)
    s$stop()
  }


  # run shiny server
  sink(stderr())
  options(bitmapType='cairo')
  getOption("bitmapType")
  print("test")
  write("prints to stderr", stderr())
  write("prints to stdout", stdout())
  write(port, stdout())
  runApp('shiny-frontend',port=myPort,host="0.0.0.0",launch.browser=F)
}
```

And my `init.r`, looks like this:

```
install.packages("shiny", clean=T)
install.packages("Rook", clean=T)
```

Then when I run, everything is deployed correctly, but then when I try to go by the route, I see an error in the log:

```
* ERR Calls: <Anonymous> -> startDynamicHelp
* ERR Execution halted
* ERR Error in startDynamicHelp(FALSE) : could not find function "httpdPort"
```

I also noticed that assigned port is different every time, which is weird and the route in bluemix dashboard does not mention it. But I output the port to the log, and use that number.

Also the way I'm doing it seems a bit too complicated, so if anybody could suggest any easier way, I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it took me a while to understand that this error is thrown by R because it can not find the **function** (not the value) `httpdPort`. Instead of binding `httpdPort` to a function you are binding it to a value. The line `s$stop()` is the one causing trouble. It calls `startDynamicHelp` that assumes that httpdPort is a function defined in the environment `tools`.

To fix this issue you can change the block `if (status == 0){...}` in your code to:

```
if (status == 0) {
    getSettable <- function(default){
                       function(obj = NA){if(!is.na(obj)){default <<- obj};
                                  default}
                   }
    myHttpdPort <- getSettable(myPort)
    unlockBinding("httpdPort", environment(tools:::startDynamicHelp))
    assign("httpdPort", myHttpdPort, environment(tools:::startDynamicHelp))

    s <- Rhttpd$new()
    s$listenAddr <- myInterface
    s$listenPort <- myPort

    s$print()
    Sys.sleep(60)
    s$stop()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Breno!