# Deploy Rook Apps in R internal web server

Tags: r, r-rook-package

I develop a Rook Apps and it works perfectly . so i want to deploy under Rstudio with different IP and PORT: so i use the code of jeffrey horner :

http://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/33814488298/deploy-rook-apps-part-ii

But, doesn't work! with lastest Rook commit in github and R version 3.4.3 :

```
 Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg) , inherits =FALSE):
object 'startHTTPD' introuvable 
calls : ::: -> get
```

Actually, if you check the package tools:: . the function startHTTPD doesn't exsit any more in tools:: environment. [Breno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401466/deployed-r-app-with-shiny-crash-with-could-not-find-function-httpdport) try to fix this, but, still the same problem to me.

Any one cross this problem or have i solution .

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know whether this would solve your issue, but for using `Rook` with RStudio I use `devtools::install_github("filipstachura/Rook")` instead of the CRAN package.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to answer this, but this had me stumped and I figured it out.  The function name has changed, recently to "C_startHTTPD".  So that code you need to start an internal http server for rook is now:

```
if (as.integer(R.version[["svn rev"]]) > 59600) {
  status <- .Call(tools:::C_startHTTPD, myInterface, myPort)
} else {
  status <- .Internal(C_startHTTPD(myInterface, myPort))
}
```